# ms charts with caching?

Tags: .net, caching, mschart, outputcache

I put my implementation of mscharts 4.0 in a user control and it works great - just have to set a couple parameters and go.

I then went to cache the charts because some of them do some pretty intense work, but I get a broken image link when going back to a cached control.  I am caching with this line in the ascx:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="28800" VaryByParam="*" %>
```

I figured the control would cache the temp image that the charthandler created but evidently not.  Has anyone ever come across a solution to this?

Comment: Facing the same problem, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Not really - I was pressed for time so instead of solving the charting problem I cached pages and/or calculations the charts used. If you find a solution to this actual problem please post it

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Mario, I will post here if I find a solution